# Defining custom classpath for a jar manifest in gradle

Tags: jar, classpath, manifest, gradle

I'm trying to define a jar task for all sub projects (about 30). I tried the following task:

```
 jar {
            destinationDir = file('../../../../_temp/core/modules')
            archiveName = baseName + '.' + extension
            metaInf {
                    from 'ejbModule/META-INF/' exclude 'MANIFEST.MF'
            }

          def manifestClasspath = configurations.runtime.collect { it.getName() }.join(',') 
            manifest {
            attributes("Manifest-Version"       : "1.0",
                "Created-By"             : vendor,
                "Specification-Title"    : appName,
                "Specification-Version"  : version,
                "Specification-Vendor"   : vendor,
                "Implementation-Title"   : appName,
                "Implementation-Version" : version,
                "Implementation-Vendor"  : vendor,
                "Main-Class"             : "com.dcx.epep.Start",
                "Class-Path"             : manifestClasspath 
            )
            }
    }
```

My problem is, that the dependencies between the sub projects are not included in the manifest's classpath. I tried changing the runtime configuration to a compile configuration but that results in the following error.

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':EskoordClient'.
>
> > You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!

That is my complete build file for project EskoordClient:

```
dependencies {     
    compile project(':ePEPClient')
}
```

Most of my sub projects build files only define the projects dependencies. 3rd party lib dependencies are defined in the build file of the super project.

Is there a possibility to include all needed classpath entries (3rd party libraries and other projects) to a manifest classpath in a superproject for all subprojects.

Comment: Do you declare that task for every subproject? (I don't see a `subprojects {}` block.) The "can't change configuration" error occurs because you are doing the work too early (configuration phase instead of execution phase). Project dependencies are correctly included for me. Which Gradle version are you using?

Comment: I'm using gradle Version 1.0

Currently I have the jar target in a configure `operation:configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name.endsWith('Service') || it.name.endsWith('Common') || it.name.endsWith('Client')})`

Answer (score 5):

This is how I got it to work. Get Project dependencies only using the call:

```
getAllDependencies().withType(ProjectDependency)
```

then adding the contents of each project's libsDir to my Class-Path manifest entry.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.my.package.Main'
        def manifestCp = configurations.runtime.files.collect  {
        File file = it
        "lib/${file.name}"
        }.join(' ')


         configurations.runtime.getAllDependencies().withType(ProjectDependency).each {dep->

            def depProj = dep.getDependencyProject()
            def libFilePaths = project(depProj.path).libsDir.list().collect{ inFile-> "lib/${inFile}"  }.join(' ')
            logger.info"Adding libs from project ${depProj.name}: [- ${libFilePaths} -]"
            manifestCp += ' '+libFilePaths
        }

        logger.lifecycle("")
        logger.lifecycle("---Manifest-Class-Path: ${manifestCp}")
        attributes 'Class-Path': manifestCp

    }

}
```

Comment: you may want to remove duplicates from the final classpath and sort them using `manifestCp = manifestCp.split(' ').collect().unique().sort().join(' ')` ... i love groovy